# Google Charts Tooltips-Annotations

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

My google chart will have 3-4 data series, and when the user puts their mouse on the chart I would like the tooltip to show each series data point in the tooltip at the same time including the date (haxis).

Does anyone know how I might add the tooltips the way I described above?

```
     var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Year', 'Data1', 'Data2', 'Data3'],
          [new Date(2001, 01, 01), 30, 20, 1000],
          [new Date(2002, 01, 01), 70, 20, 1000],
...

var options = {
          colors: ['#ffffff', '#ffffff', '#ffffff'],
          hAxis: {
            slantedText: true,
            slantedTextAngle: 45,
            gridlines: {
              color: 'f2f2f2'
            }
          },
          vAxis: {
            minValue: 0,
            gridlines: {
              color: 'f2f2f2'
            }
          },
          series: {
            0: {
              type: 'area',
              areaOpacity: 0.25,
              lineWidth: 1.5
            },
            1: {
              type: 'line',
              lineWidth: 1.5
            },
            2: {
              type: 'line',
              lineWidth: 1.5,
              targetAxisIndex: 1
            },
          },
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following configuration option...

```
aggregationTarget: 'category'
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  We ended up using:

focusTarget: 'category',